# Dynamic SQL - something up with the where clause

Tags: sql

I have this proc:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
@TableName nvarchar(100), 
@RowID int

AS
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery = 'Select * from ' + @TableName + ' where ID = ' + @RowID ; 
    EXECUTE(@SQLQuery); 
END
```

I basically want to return the resulting row from this, without a where clause, its all good.

Comment: Looks right for what you want to do (regardless of the SQL Injection vulnerability). What's not working?

Comment: If I take out the where clause I get results. But with where clause in I get : Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Select * from [TableName] where ID = ' to data type int.

Comment: Add a print @SQLQuery and you can run the generated query and check if it returns rows

Comment: @JL - Convert the `INT` to a string. `CONVERT(@RowID AS VARCHAR)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be very careful as you've opened yourself up to SQL injection attacks. I'd strongly recommend being very defensive with this and parameterise as much as possible. e.g.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
@TableName nvarchar(100), 
@RowID int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(500); 
    IF (OBJECT_ID(@TableName) IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLQuery = 'Select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' where ID = @RowId' 
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@RowId INTEGER', @RowID
        END
END
```

It would also be worth considering "locking down" what @TableName values are explicitly supported - check against a whitelist before building/executing the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks Ada, works like a charm, I decided to do it your way to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

in case that ID is varchar try this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
@TableName nvarchar(100), 
@RowID int

AS
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery = 'Select * from ' + @TableName + ' where ID = ''' + rtrim(ltrim(str(@RowID))) + ''''; 
    EXECUTE(@SQLQuery); 
END
```